# Django dynamic admin forms

Tags: django, model, admin

I am having trouble with some django admin functionalities
what I want to do is to have 2 fields in an admin page
and I want to achieve this

field_A

field_B

if field_A == "specific value":
exclude = ("field_B",)

else:
fields = ("field_A","field_B")

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

at last I gave up with django manipulating the DOM (which I think it cant do on real time) and made it with a Jquery Script

Comment: How did you link the values given in the new field created to the model? Could you provide small explanation? Sorry I'm kind of new at Django.